# Neo4J - Prevent duplicated relationship types with identical meaning

Tags: neo4j, data-modeling, graph-databases

Consider Person nodes and Item nodes.

What is the best way to prevent having both 'Purchased' type relationships and 'Bought' type relationships in the graph that have the same meaning, but are simply named differently?

E.g. if we end up with our graph in a state like:

```
(Alice) -[Bought]   -> (Pickles)
(Bob)   -[Purchased]-> (Pickles)
```

and I want to know everyone who has bought a jar of pickles. Clearly someone made a mistake when creating one of these relationships. How do I prevent that class of mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limit the relationships a user can create to a specific set of names, and don't allow any other relationship names.

Comment: Is this something you can do with Neo4J itself, or do you mean from a home-rolled app/api layer?

Comment: This would be an app imposed constraint.